# How to write a test method for createNewToken Method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to this Mockito J-Unit Testing and I want to test my `createNewToken()`-Method but I cant understand the logic of it.

This is my method:

```
public String createNewToken(String usertoken) {
    WebToken oldToken = getTokenByUserToken(usertoken);
    if (!Assert.isNull(oldToken)) {
        em.remove(oldToken);
    }
    WebToken webToken = new WebToken();
    webToken.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    webToken.setUserToken(usertoken);
    em.persist(webToken);

    return webToken.getToken();
}
```

And this is my test method but i am sure it is wrong:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class WebTokenPSTest extends AbstractPersistenceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    WebTokenPS cut;

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public static class createNewToken extends WebTokenPSTest {

        @Test
        public void happyPath() {
            String token = cut.createNewToken("token");
            String result = token;
            assertThat(result).isEqualTo(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tthe main parts of your method works with Hibernate EntityManager,  as I can see. So you should test this part, or mock it if possible.

Also you can mock getTokenByUserToken(userToket). Here you can write several cases.

So the possible test cases:

- getTokenByUserToken(usertoken) return null. So your method creates new Token and persist token to DB. The assertion `em.createQuery("select token t....")`. Here you validate that new token persists to DB
- getTokenByUserToken(usertoken) return not persisted in DB token. Here you can expect the exception, when the EntityManager tries to remove this token. It's a good way to find, that some exception cases aren't properly handled in the code
- getTokenByUserToken(usertoken) returns existing token (you can insert it to DB before this test for example). Here you test the removing of existing token and creating of the new token.